# how can I convert a char to variable?

Tags: python

In detail:
I need this formula to work.
`string = str(z)+":1.0 "+str(z+1)+":0.0"`      where z is a variable with a value.

will I be able to input this formula into a dictionary value with a specific key. Like

```
dicto={'A': 'str(z)+":1.0 "+str(z+1)+":0.0"'}
```

so that when i see a key value 'A' I should be able to use that formula in the dictionary

Comment: I think you want a function, not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [lambda function](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html):

```
d = { 'A': lambda z: str(z)+":1.0 "+str(z+1)+":0.0" }

d['A'](5)

# returns: '5:1.0 6:0.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

As I read your question, you wanted something like this:

```
dicto = {'A': lambda x: "{0!s}:1.0 {1!s}:0.0".format(x, x + 1)}
dicto['A'](2)   # '2:1.0 3:0.0'
```